# what is the idea behind making dismissDialog() throw an exception?

Tags: android, dialog, android-activity

Is it not better design to just return false if not found and true otherwise? now i have to either make sure i am dismissing a shown dialog or to sorround every call with try and catch... anyone can tell/guess why would they think that this is a good design?

it seem also like they made dismissDialog() final cause i cant override it can i?

thanks!

Comment: Because it would be *bad* design to do it your way.  People would write lazy code and just dismiss dialogs (or try to) without understanding if they are showing or not, and why.  If you want to do it your way, just test if its visible before dismissing - `if(dialog.isShowing())`

Answer (score 0):

I would use as alternative `removeDialog()` without throw exception.

Further, both methods were deprecated in API level 13.

so use [DialogFragment](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/DialogFragment.html)

Comment: but then it will recreate the dialog which is worse

Comment: you mean `removeDialog`?

Comment: right but how many dialogs you show up.  but I suggest  you anyways to use `DialogFragment`, because one day it will give you additional work to change your old code.